# overlapping prefix words regex

Tags: python, regex

how can I deal with situations where the prefix words that I am declaring overlap? 
In this example, I am looking for whatever comes after hello or world but when the words are combined I want regex to move over to the second in line and give me whats after that. I hope that makes sense.
Here's what I have:

```
(?:hello|world)(?:.*?\s+\S+)
```

Result looks like this:

- **hello 234234sdf** sfs
- **world 23424f**
- **hello world:** sdfrwefwggds

**bold** represents the highlighted areas

For the `hello world: sdfrwefwggds` example, im looking for `sdfrwefwggds`

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `(?:hello|world)(?!\s+(?:hello|world))(.*?\s+\S+)`

Comment: this works but there could be situation where the word 'hello' could extend to something else like 'hellothere world'

Comment: Then replace `(?!\s+(?:hello|world))` with `(?!\w*\s+(?:hello|world))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes! thanks so much!

Comment: Posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
 (?:hello|world)(?!\w*\s+(?:hello|world))(.*?\s+\S+)
```

See the [Python demo](https://regex101.com/r/5YxQY2/2).

**Details**

- `(?:hello|world)` - either of the two words
- `(?!\w*\s+(?:hello|world))` -  immediately to the right of the current location, there can't be

  - `\w*` - 0+ word chars (use `[^\W\d_]*` to only match letters)
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:hello|world)` - either of the two words
- `(.*?\s+\S+)` - Group 1:

  - `.*?` - 0+ chars, as few as possible, other than line break chars
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\S+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace